# Imprimir várias matrizes separadamente

Tags: c, matriz

Gostaria de saber se tem como imprimir essas três matrizes sem que tenha de criar vários `for's`, a impressão das mesmas na tela deve ser separada. ( preciso de uma alternativa por que tenho pouco espaço e o código ficou bem extenso quando fui imprimir da maneira convencional )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () { setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    int mat1[100][100], mat2[100][100], mat3[100][100], linha = 0, coluna = 0;

    // red, blue, green

    printf("\nInforme o número de linhas e colunas: ");
    scanf("%i %i",&linha,&coluna);

    for ( int i = 0; i < linha; i++){
        for ( int h = 0; h < coluna; h++){
            printf("\nInforme um digito para linha %i, coluna %i matriz red: ",i, h);
            scanf("%i",&mat1[i][h]);
        }
        system("cls");
        for ( int j = 0; j < coluna; j++){
            printf("\nInforme um digito para linha %i, coluna %i matriz blue: ",i, j);
            scanf("%i",&mat2[i][j]);
        }
        system("cls");
        for ( int q = 0; q < coluna; q++){
            printf("\nInforme um digito para linha %i, coluna %i matriz green: ",i,q);
            scanf("%i",&mat3[i][q]);
        }
        system("cls");
    }

    // imprimir toda a primeira, depois a segunda e por fim a terceira...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer imprimir 3 ou mais, é melhor colocá-las juntas.

```
int matriz[3][100][100];
int x,y,z;
for(x=0; x<3; x++)
    for(y=0; y<100; y++)
        for(z=0; z<100; z++;){
            printf("entre o valor da matriz %x, linha %d, coluna %d: ", z,y,z);
            scanf("%d", &matrz[x][y][z]);
         }

for(x=0; x<3; x++)
    for(y=0; y<100; y++)
        for(z=0; z<100; z++;)
            printf("matriz %d[%d,%d]: %d",x,y,z,matriz[x][y][z]);
```

O primeiro for anda pelas matrizes (x == total de matrizes) e os outros 2 percorrem linhas e colunas.

Assim você pode percorrer quantas matrizes você quiser, e deixa o código mais organizado;